# OLE objects insert change object format

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following script to automatically insert a signature PDF image into a document to act as a signature. However when the pdf is inserted is automatically puts a border on the image which i don't want. how can i amend the format of the object to have no borders or lines.

I have tried using 'ActiveSheet.Shapes.Line.Visible = msoFalse' but this doesn't work.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Insert_signature()
' this part of the script creates a temp filename in the temp folder.
    Dim strPathname As String
    On Error Resume Next
    strPathname = "http://Clearance Handover/Forms/Signature.pdf"

    'MsgBox = ("you are formally authorising the sign off")

    Call insert_pdf_to_Checklist1(strPathname)
End Sub

Sub insert_pdf_to_Checklist1(pdfpath As String)
Dim Xl, Ws, Ol
' This creates an image of the pdf created and
    Set Ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Checklist1")
    Set Ol = Ws.OLEObjects.Add(, pdfpath, False, False)

         With Ol
            .Left = Ws.Range("E48:E48").Left
            .Height = Ws.Range("E48:E48").Height
            .Width = Ws.Range("E48:E48").Width
            .Top = Ws.Range("E48:E48").Top
         End With
End Sub
```

Cheers Guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below Code should work :) . **Tested**

```
Option Explicit
Sub Insert_signature()
    Dim strPathname As String
    strPathname = "C:\Users\ksathis\Documents\Outlook Files\VBASQL.pdf"
    Call insert_pdf_to_Checklist1(strPathname)
End Sub

Sub insert_pdf_to_Checklist1(pdfpath As String)
Dim Xl, Ws
Dim ole As OLEObject
    Set Ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Checklist1")
    Set ole = Ws.OLEObjects.Add(, pdfpath, False, False)
    With ole
            .Left = Ws.Range("E48:E48").Left
            .Height = Ws.Range("E48:E48").Height
            .Width = Ws.Range("E48:E48").Width
            .Top = Ws.Range("E48:E48").Top
            .Interior.Color = vbWhite
            .Border.LineStyle = 0
            .Border.Color = vbWhite
         End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I was so hopeful!!!!! But unfortunately it doesn't work with the sheet im using.  I don't understand why it isn't working, this is driving me MAD! LOL

Comment: No the script just runs fine, which is exactly what it did with every other solution i have tried. It almost like the OLE object isn't there. I have tried recording macro's to change the boarder setting and the change occurs but the recorded Macro ends up showing blank. Very strange!